# Given a string, how can we multiply individual characters in a string without using join() or regular expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`paper_doll('Hello')` --> 'HHHeeellllllooo'

`paper_doll('Mississippi')` --> 'MMMiiissssssiiippppppiii'

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh sorry for that! I'm new to this! Will provide more details next time! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You could go the old-fashioned route and build a new string by iterating through the original string:

```
def paper_doll(astr):
    newstr = ""
    for char in astr:
        newstr += char*3
    return newstr
```